# jQuery UI slide animation with height fix only works first time

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, animation, slide

I've got a search function loading results with ajax and shows the results using a slide animation. Works great! But only the first time unfortunately, the second time (and onwards) the slide down animation doesn't work.

Please have a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/e4sQh/4/

The search is'nt performed there and no ajax data is loaded but you get the point. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your setting the height to `0` is inside your `if` check (which is only true the first time) here:

```
  // get the original height
  if( !height ){
    // get original height
    height = $el.show().height();
    // update the height
    $el.data("originalHeight", height);
    // if the element was hidden, hide it again
    if( !visible ) $el.hide().css({height: 0});
  }
```

It needs to be moved outside like this:

```
  // get the original height
  if( !height ){
    // get original height
    height = $el.show().height();
    // update the height
    $el.data("originalHeight", height);
  }
  // if the element was hidden, hide it again
  if( !visible ) $el.hide().css({height: 0});
```

This way it hides *every* time appropriately, [you can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/MqzaS/1/).

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
slideToggle('#results',true); // inside hideLoading()
```

**with**

```
content.slideDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this part is wrong

```
if( !height ){
    // get original height
    height = $el.show().height();
    // update the height
    $el.data("originalHeight", height);
    // if the element was hidden, hide it again
    if( !visible ) $el.hide().css({height: 0});
  }
```

You show element to get its height, so it doesn't slide as it's visible!

You should use `css()` method to set `position:absolute`, `visibility:hidden` and `display:block`.

Anyway JQuery provides method which replace your function, take a look on [slides](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)